# How to partition a probability distribution function to find expected value?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, monte-carlo

Given a probability distribution function $p(x)$, the corresponding cumulative distribution function $F(x)$ and $y(x)$ which is computationally expensive to evaluate, I would like to find the expected value of $y$. To do this within a reasonable amount of time, I could only evaluate $y(x)$ $n$ times. How should I find "key points" $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n}$ so that $\sum_i y(x_i) (F(x_i)-F(x_{i-1}))$ best approximates $\int y(x)p(x)\ \mathrm{d}x$? I imagine I'd have to evaluate more points where $p(x)$ is large.

A general solution would be great, but if that's not possible we could assume $p(x)$ is a Gaussian function and $y(x)$ is the sum of a series of sinusoidal functions.

---

Update:

If it helps we can also make the assumptions that

1. $-1\leq x\leq 1$, and $p(x)$ is a truncated Gaussian with $\mu=0,\sigma=1/4$
2. $y(x)=Y_1 \sin(k x+\phi)+Y_0$
3. The Riemann sum I proposed above is to be replaced with a better discrete integration method $\mathrm{int}((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),\cdots(x_n,y_n))$

---

Update 2:

I am using a naive strategy which is to divide $[0,1]$ evenly and find their inverse CDF, i.e. $u_i=F^{-1}(i/n), \quad i=0,1,\cdots,n$, and then let $x_i=(u_{i-1}+u_i)/2$. This way each subdivision of the interval of integration has the same weight. This reaches the same error level as equally-spaced partitioning with a constant number of less evaluations of $y$. But I can not prove its optimality and it does not generalize well when dealing with multiple integrals.

I found [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html) how Mathematica handles with this. But none of them are as good as my naive method given the same amount of evaluation of $y$. I think it's because they are not fully utilizing the information on the easily calculable $p$.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to restrict yourself to a right-sided Riemann sum? This is one of the worst integration rules, even worse than the [rectangle rule and trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#Quadrature_rules_based_on_interpolating_functions), which are just as simple. Are you aware of [Gaussian quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature)? To give a concrete suggestion, we'd have to know the range of $x$.

Comment: @joriki Not really, it's just easier to type up. Thanks for the info on Gaussian quadrature, I'll read into it.

Comment: Do we know $F$?

Comment: @JackM yeah $F(x)=\int_{-1}^{x} p(u) \ \mathrm{d}u$ so close to an $\mathrm{erf}$